# crear una lista con un arreglo con triple ciclo for en python

Tags: python, bucle-for, bucles

he intentado abordar este problema de diferentes formas pero aun no he podido resolverlo, quiero incluir los valores seleccionados de forma random en cada uno de los arreglos de mi lista, pero obtengo un resultado totalmente diferente a lo que quiero

importando paquetes

```
import pandas as pd
import random
```

generando numeros aleatoreos

````
Poisson_list = np.random.poisson(30, 8)
Poisson_list
Lista_Fondo_jugador = [20000,25000,30000,35000,40000,45000,50000,55000,60000,65000,70000,75000,80000,85000,90000,95000,100000,105000,110000,115000,120000]
h = 0
Lista_llegadas = []
for i in Poisson_list:
    h += 1
    Min = np.random.choice(np.arange(0, 60), i)
    Min.sort()
    plata_jugador = np.random.choice((20000,150000,5000),i)
    Lista_llegadas.extend([(h, j, (h - 1) * 60 + j) for j in Min])
    Lista_llegadas.append(Lista_Fondo_jugador )
Lista_llegadas```

lo que obtengo es:
[(1, 1, 1),
 (1, 2, 2),
 (1, 3, 3),
 (1, 56, 56),
 (1, 57, 57),
 (1, 58, 58),
 (1, 58, 58),
 [20000,
  25000,
  30000,
  50000,
  55000,
  60000,
  65000,
  70000,
  75000,
  80000,
  85000,
  90000,
  95000,],....

realmente me gustaría obtener:[(1, 1, 1,5000),(1, 2, 2,1000),....

no sé que cambio deba hacerle a mi código para poder arreglarlo de tal forma que obtenga un resultado como el que busco.

estaré muy agradecido si me pueden ayudar.
````

Answer (score 0):

logre atacar el problema de esta forma en donde se tenga de forma aleatoria la ultima parte del arreglo

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
Poisson_list = np.random.poisson(30, 8)
Poisson_list
Lista_Fondo_jugador = [20000,25000,30000,35000,40000,45000,50000,55000,60000,65000,70000,75000,80000,85000,90000,95000,100000,105000,110000,115000,120000]
h = 0
Lista_llegadas = []
for i in Poisson_list:
    h += 1
    Min = np.random.choice(np.arange(0, 60), i)
    Min.sort()
    Lista_llegadas.extend([(h, j, (h - 1) * 60 + j, np.random.choice(Lista_Fondo_jugador ) ) for j in Min])
Lista_llegadas
```